# CSS Stylesheet for Website

Tags: html, css, web, styles, stylesheet

**Solved by Nick R**

Can someone please help me with this, my stylesheet isn't loading on my site and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

This is the HTML I have :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../files/styles/website.css" media="ALL"></link>
  </head>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS Code :

```
@charset "utf-8"
body {
  background-color:#FF0000
}
```

Comment: may be the file path is wrong.

Comment: Firstly, put a ; at the end of your `background-color` line. Secondly, double check that the file is at the location specified.

Comment: Define "isn't loading."  Is the file not found by the web request?  Is the style not being applied as expected?  How does it fail?

Comment: Well right now, you have no `<body>` tag so there's nothing for the background colour to apply to...

Comment: It's not being detected i think

Comment: please check console, is there any error of css not loading?

Comment: Remove `</link>`, as the link is self closing, so change it to  `media="ALL" />`. In the CSS file, you're missing a `;`, after `@charset "utf-8"`, it should be `@charset "utf-8";`. And you also have no `<body>` tag in your `HTML`.

Comment: Most probably, your CSS is not reachable with the pack  you specified. Make sure you are providing the path correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../files/styles/website.css">
    </head>
</html>
```

check your path, if this won't work try to use absolute path

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yourdomain.com/files/styles/website.css">
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OS X or Linux, Maybe the problem is your folder permission

Try to write this on your terminal :

```
$ chmod -R 777 folder # Change folder to your folder names
```